# The smallest prime which is not a factor

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

For any $n\geq 2$, let $f(n)=\min\{\text{prime }p: p\nmid n\}$. What is the best bound one can claim for $f(n)$ in terms of $n$?

I think $f(n)\leq \sqrt{n}$, but do not know whether this can be improved.

Comment: Your $f(n)$ is wrong for $n=2,3,4$.

Comment: The strongest bound you can claim for $f(n)$ is that it cannot exceed $f(n)$.

Comment: Anyways, for what you're probably looking for, try considering the inverse problem: compute the $g$ such that $$g(p) = \min\{n : f(n) = p \}$$

Comment: If $f(n) > p_k$, then $n \geqslant p_1\cdot \dotsc \cdot p_k = \exp(\vartheta(p_k)) \approx e^{p_k}$. So you can almost bound $f(n)$ by $\log n$.

Comment: Can I say that for sufficiently large $n$, $f(n)\leq \log n$? If this is true, do we have a concrete $N$ such that for any $n\geq N$, $f(n)\leq \log n$?

Comment: And also wrong for $n=6,8,12,18,24,30$.